# Відповідник словосполученню "cold chain"

Tags: переклад, from-english, терміни, словосполучення

Шукаю більш милозвучний відповідник словосполученню "cold chain" - мається на увазі сукупність засобів, приладів (машин) та дій по забезпеченню збереження харчових продуктів від лану до столу. На всьому шляху від виробника до споживача. **Холодильний ланцюг** звучить трохи кострубато і, на мою думку, не всім зрозуміло.

Answer (score 4):

[«Порядок забезпечення належних умов зберігання, транспортування, приймання та обліку вакцин, анатоксинів та алергену туберкульозного в Україні»](https://zakon.rada.gov.ua/laws/show/z1166-11), а за ним і [українська вікіпедія](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%86%D1%8E%D0%B3) пишуть **холодовий ланцюг** (не *холодильний*). Щоправда перший уживає це словосполучення в лапках.